# Theme switch when accessed from sub domain

Tags: subdomains

Need to switch theme when accessed from sub domain. There is nothing installed in the sub domain. I have setup a subdomain as a CNAME pointing to the original domain. Then, detect whether or not the visitor is on the subdomain by looking at $_SERVER[‘SERVER_NAME’]. Went through various sources and have found out this code but could not make this working.

Note: I am a newbie

```
// regular site url
$my_url = 'http://example.com';

// subdomain you want a different theme on
$my_sub_url = 'http://sub.example.com';

// subdomain prefix, used to test whether primary or subdomain
$my_prefix = 'sub.';

// folder name of theme to use instead on subdomain
$my_theme_name = 'my_mobile_theme';


add_filter( 'template'          , 'my_change_theme' );
add_filter( 'option_template'   , 'my_change_theme' );
add_filter( 'option_stylesheet' , 'my_change_theme' );

// these 2 actions rewrite all urls in the body
// from main to sub domain
add_action( 'wp_head'           , 'my_buffer_start' );
add_action( 'wp_footer'         , 'my_buffer_end' );

// TRUE, if this is the subdomain, false otherwise
public function my_is_subdomain() {
  global $my_prefix;
  if( strpos( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $my_prefix ) !== FALSE ) {
    return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}

// if this is the subdomain, return new theme
// otherwise, return original theme
public function my_change_theme( $theme ) {
  global $my_theme_name;
  if( my_is_subdomain() ) {
    return $my_theme_name;
  }
  return $theme;
}

public function my_buffer_start() {
  ob_start('my_buffer_cb');
}

public function my_buffer_end() {
  ob_end_flush();
}

// replace primary url with subdomain url in body
// so that all links keep user on the subdomain
public function my_buffer_cb( $buffer ) {
  global $my__url, $my_sub_url;
  if( ! my_is_subdomain() ) {
    return $buffer;
  }

  // replace main domain with sub domain
  $buffer = str_replace( $my_url, $my_sub_url, $buffer);

  // !!! NOTE - you may not want to replace EVERY instance
  // for example, you may want to keep social media urls
  // intact, or rel="canonical", or links specifically
  // designed to switch between the primary and subdomain

  return $buffer;
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] and reformat your code

Comment: Where you found this code @venkatguru?

Comment: @prosti here http://craiget.com/blog/using-a-different-wordpress-theme-on-a-subdomain/

Answer (score 1):

WordPress supports only one theme on site. Actions like shown will cause a  adverse effects.
Instead, you should use WordPress Multisite, which allows to use different themes on subdomains. This is the way recommended by the WordPress team.

There is solution for WooCommerce on WordPress Multisite: [WooCommerce  Multistore plugin:](https://woomultistore.com)   It is quite expensive ($200), but struggling with unsupported features in WordPress can cost much more.

Comment: I have a woocommerce site, I wish to have a separate theme for mobile (web) and mobile app (android webview app). Multisite site does not sync woocommerce data with the mainsite which makes it unusable. Kindly let me know your suggestions.

Comment: I have edited my answer in accordance with new info about WooCommerce.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend The Woocommerce Multistore plugin as described in KAGG Design's answer.

It's overall very slow, which is very bad for the stock synchronization.
It also supports WPML which is one of the worst plugins, that overloading your database and will kill your store overtime.

For this reason I went with Woocommerce Multistore by Mrinvent.
It's a platform that manages realtime stock synchronization, PIM management, order management and Multilingual.

You can pay per month, which makes it cheaper and easier to try.

https://mrinvent.online